# How can I move my work location in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Google is convinced I work about 500m from where I really do.

For three months I've been working at "Integratech Limited" in this picture, and spend 8 hours a day there (with my GPS enabled phone), but somehow Google ignore this and think I'm down the road.

[image]

How can I force this to change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Selecting **[My Places](http://maps.google.com/maps/myplaces)** within Google Maps will give you a list of your saved/starred locations. Clicking the dropdown next to **Work** will let you *Edit* the address there.

Google also have a [help topic](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/1626958) on this subject.

[image: google maps my places]

Comment: Ah, screen shots. Your answer is better than mine.

Comment: Thanks, that should work but doesn't. I try entering my work address and it doesn't find it, yet I enter the same address into the search box and it does. I then try lat long (52.21605, -2.18171), which locates the exact position if I search for it but if I enter it as the Work location and the click Work to go to the work location then it goes to a point just next to the original wrong work location down the road. Very weird.

Comment: @cja is your work saved as a google place?

Comment: @batpigandme Yes - https://www.google.co.uk/maps?q=Integratech+Limited,+1,+Shire+Business+Park,+Wainwright+Rd,+Worcester&sll=52.19651399990242,-2.210405244282089&sspn=0.09985917305855627,0.2884352090485108&t=m&dg=opt&hq=Integratech+Limited,+1,+Shire+Business+Park,&hnear=Wainwright+Rd,+Worcester+WR4,+United+Kingdom&z=16&iwloc=A

Comment: Google maps has multiple locations showing for your address. Three in fact ([C & D & E in this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq266.png)) have the same address, so Google is defaulting to the coordinates with the most pointers for your address.

Comment: Try entering your Work Address as [WR4 4BQ](https://www.google.co.uk/maps?q=WR4%204BQ) as that gets you a lot closer to your actual office.

Comment: Ok so I haven't done anything but somehow my work location is now accurate. Magic.